# Plug-in supply with ac output

Tags: power-supply

I have a plug-in-supply unit with "220V ac 50Hz" input and "12V rms" output.
My question: Does anybody know how the waveform and the frequency looks like for such a off-the-shelf device?

**EDIT**: It is an italian device called "Transformatore elettronico" and the weight is only 70 grams. So it is kind of switched power supply - however with an ac output.
That was the background of my question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be answered in the device documentation.

Comment: @LeonHeller -- if it came with any :P

Comment: Without knowing what the device is this its impossible to answer.  The simplest would be a transformer in which case the output would be approximately the same shape as the input except smaller so a (distorted) sine wave but if for example its switch mode it could be anything -- does it have a make and model?.

Comment: Is the plug-in-supply heavy = Probably a transformer = @ThreePhaseEel is close to the truth.

Comment: Either read the datasheet for the device or look at its output on a scope.  Otherwise, we'd just be guessing from the very scant information you have supplied.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the device is light-weight; so I doubt that it s just a wired transformer.

Comment: Please read my EDIT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would likely be a SMPS intended for driving Halogen lamps with 12Vac or compatible lamps.

The primary is FW rectified then creates a T1 relaxation oscillator to drive a halfbridge and step-down transformer at higher f such that a smaller core can be used. The Vdc is split by two plastic caps to create a bipolar hi Vdc supply with centre tap of the caps to transformer input on one side and L C filtered to driver output with complementary switches.

T1 provides the ultrasonic switching clock rate (eg>20kHz) with positive feedback, while the diac triggers AM to modulate this carrier at twice the line frequency to drive T1 with more Ac current.

e.g.

[image]

The waveform would look pretty ugly depending on load and rich in harmonics of 1f, 2f with carrier fosc.  EMI?? but it just serves to drive lamps.

Comment: Tony - thank you. You are right - it is the purpose of the device to drive a halogen lamp. However, the problem is that it does not work properly : From time to time it fails and I`ve got the imprerssion that it is the oscillator which is the cause of the problem. Last Question: The output is a pulse - having frequency of app. 20kHz - AM modulated with 50 Hz. Is this correct?

Comment: my guess is 100hz as FW bridge is a frequency doubler  A soft start ICL may boost the starting stability on output.